# Strange behaviour with CGI

Tags: apache, bash, cgi, raspberry-pi

I've a small project almost finished. In it, I use some `.cgi` files in which I make communication between a microcontroler and a webserver. The problem is the following:

If I use this code the project works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

./moveRight

echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
```

but when I use this code, nothing happens:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""

mkdir /tmp/stream
raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th      0:0:0 &
chmod 777 /dev/ttyAMA0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i "input_file.so -f /tmp/stream -n pic.jpg" -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -w /var/www" &
```

What I want is to execute those bash commands when the `.cgi` is called, do you think what can be my problem? Or any workaround for this issue?

Comment: what does ./moveRight do? you don't call it in the second example...

Comment: Start the script with `#!/bin/bash` `set -x` `exec 2> /tmp/cgi-log`. This will give you an error log to look at.

Comment: ./moveRight is a compiled c program which moves a motor. I have two different  .cgi. The first one moves the motor correctly but the second one is supposed to execute some shell commands but when it's called, nothing happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour with CGI file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425289/strange-behaviour-with-cgi-file)