# Strange behaviour with CGI file

Tags: apache, bash, cgi, raspberry-pi

I've a small project allmost finished. In it, I use some .cgi files in which I make communication between a microcontroler and a webserver. The problem is the following:

If I use this code the project works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

./moveRight

echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
```

but when I use tjis code, nothing happens:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/stream
raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th      0:0:0 &
chmod 777 /dev/ttyAMA0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i "input_file.so -f /tmp/stream -n pic.jpg" -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -w /var/www" &


echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
```

What I want is to execute those bash commands when the .cgi is called, do you think what can be my problem? Or any workaround for this issue?

EDIT: ./moveRight is a compiled c program which moves a motor. I have two different .cgi. The first one moves the motor correctly but the second one is supposed to execute some shell commands but when it's called, nothing happens.

Thank you!!

Comment: Don't you need to set a PATH for mkdir, raspistill, chmod and mjpg_streamer? Don't you need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @MarkSetchell There is a PATH set by default, as it is inherited by the web server running the CGI script.  It might not be correct, agreed, but in general you do not have to set one yourself.  And things like `mkdir` are most likely in the PATH.  The special executable `mjpg_streamer` however, that might well not be in the PATH, so the PATH should be extended or a complete path to the executable should be used.

Comment: @MarkSetchell   You do _not_ have to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in this case because it is set especially for the one command given behind its setting.  The syntax `a=b c …` is executing `c` with variable `a` set to value `b`.

Comment: @Alfe I am aware there is a default PATH, I was just pointing out it should be set/extended suitably to cover all executables the OP is relying on - exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exec 2> /tmp/my.log` as first command in your script.  It redirects stderr to a file, so you can view it later, and then continues with executing the script with that redirection installed.

Place `echo "before mkdir" 1>&2` etc. *between* the commands.  This way you will see in the log how far you get in your script.  Probably you just have a command in the script which does not terminate.  Then your web browser will hang until a timeout occurs.

Comment: Are you sure both scripts (the working one and the not-working one) are alike in all important aspects?  Are both executable and readable for the web server user?  Are both in a directory the web server user is allowed to use?  Do your web server log files offer any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the HTTP header first and execute your command after:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""

mkdir /tmp/stream
raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th      0:0:0 &
chmod 777 /dev/ttyAMA0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i "input_file.so -f /tmp/stream -n pic.jpg" -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -w /var/www" &
```

Indeed, if the shell commands are printing something on stdout, you will have a `status 500` because your HTTP header is not correct.